# How to get post of only current user in django

Tags: python, django

i want that all the user can see only their own list and i getting error from django i don't know why.
Also i want create view and list view on same page which i am not able to do. i need help in this aswell.
Thank You

this is my model.py:-

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.


class simpleList(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

this is my views.py:-

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView
from .models import simpleList
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
# Create your views here.


def ListListView(request):
    current_user = request.author
    user_list = simpleList.objects.filter(user=current_user)
    return render(render, 'templates/list_list.html', {'userlist': user_list})


class CreateList(CreateView):
    model = simpleList
    template_name = 'create_list.html'
    fields = ('title', )
    success_url = reverse_lazy('create_list')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

this is my urls.py:-

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ListListView, CreateList

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ListListView, name='list_list'),
    path('create/', CreateList.as_view(), name='create_list'),
]
```

the error i am getting from django console:-

```
AttributeError at /lists/
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'author'
```

Comment: It should be `current_user = request.user`.  Why are you doing current_user = `request.author`? I don't suppose you have modified something  in middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def ListListView(request):
    current_user = request.user
    user_list = simpleList.objects.filter(author=current_user)
    return render(render, 'templates/list_list.html', {'userlist': user_list})
```

Comment: When i does this i get this error:-FieldError at /lists/
Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: author, author_id, id, title                                             I am using custom user model in project/settings.py:-AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'

Comment: This is now an issue with "user_list = simpleList.objects.filter(user=current_user)". Could you try changing "user=current_user" to "author=current_user"?

Comment: Still this error is showing up:-                                                                                                                              AttributeError at /lists/
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'author'

Comment: no it does not  but exception line is this :-   Exception Location: C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Projects\slist\slist\views.py in ListListView, line 9 and my views are :-from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView
from .models import simpleList
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
# Create your views here.


def ListListView(request):
    current_user = request.author
    user_list = simpleList.objects.filter(author=current_user)
    return render(render, 'templates/list_list.html', {'userlist': user_list})

Comment: You need to change "current_user" = request.author" to "current_user = request.user", as shown before. Try using the code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem apear in this 2 line:

```
 current_user = request.author
 user_list = simpleList.objects.filter(user=current_user)
```

The request dict dont have author name .

It should be request.user:

```
 current_user = request.user
 user_list = simpleList.objects.filter(author=current_user)
```

Comment: When i does this i get this error:-FieldError at /lists/
Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: author, author_id, id, title                                             I am using custom user model in project/settings.py:-AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'

Comment: yes you wright i didint see that you define your user with the name author :)